# Colorscheme not working for identifiers, functions and operators

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I am using Vim 7.4 (cmd). I have downloaded the vitamins color scheme and modified it a bit. But, the problem now is that the syntax highlighting works properly except for identifying `identifiers` and `operators` in, let's say, a `.cpp` file. Here is the code for my color scheme :

```
  1 " Maintainer:   Henrique C. Alves
  2 " Version:      1.1
  3 " Last Change:  September 23 2008
  4 
  5 set background=dark
  6 
  7 hi clear
  8 
  9 if exists("syntax_on")
 10   syntax reset
 11 endif
 12 
 13 let colors_name = "vitamins"
 14 
 15 " Vim >= 7.0 specific colors
 16 if version >= 700
 17   hi CursorLine guibg=#2d2d2d ctermbg=237 cterm=bold
 18   hi CursorColumn guibg=#2d2d2d ctermbg=236
 19   hi MatchParen guifg=#f6f3e8 guibg=#857b6f gui=bold ctermbg=59
 20   hi Pmenu      guifg=#f6f3e8 guibg=#444444 ctermbg=242
 21   hi PmenuSel   guifg=#000000 guibg=#cdd129 ctermfg=0 ctermbg=184
 22 endif

 24 " General colors
 25 hi Cursor       guifg=NONE    guibg=#656565 gui=none ctermbg=2
 26 hi Normal       guifg=#f6f3f0 guibg=#242424 gui=none ctermfg=254 ctermbg=234
 27 hi NonText      guifg=#808080 guibg=#303030 gui=none ctermfg=242 ctermbg=234
 28 hi LineNr       guifg=#5c5a4f guibg=#000000 gui=none ctermfg=239 ctermbg=234
 29 hi StatusLine   guifg=#f6f3e8 guibg=#444444 gui=italic ctermfg=239 ctermbg=234
 30 hi StatusLineNC guifg=#857b6f guibg=#444444 gui=none
 31 hi VertSplit    guifg=#444444 guibg=#444444 gui=none
 32 hi Folded       guibg=#384048 guifg=#a0a8b0 gui=none
 33 hi Title        guifg=#f6f3e8 guibg=NONE    gui=bold
 34 hi Visual       guifg=#ffffd7 guibg=#444444 gui=none ctermfg=186 ctermbg=238
 35 hi SpecialKey   guifg=#808080 guibg=#343434 gui=none

 37 " Syntax highlighting
 38 hi Comment      guifg=#808080 gui=italic ctermfg=186
 39 hi Todo         guifg=#8f8f8f gui=italic ctermfg=245
 40 hi Constant     guifg=#acf0f2 gui=none ctermfg=162
 41 hi String       guifg=#ff5d28 gui=italic ctermfg=154
 42 hi Identifier   guifg=#ff5d28 gui=none ctermfg=28                                                                                                                                             
 43 hi Function     guifg=#cdd129 gui=none ctermfg=142
 44 hi Type         guifg=#cdd129 gui=none ctermfg=184
 45 hi Statement    guifg=#af5f5f gui=none ctermfg=131
 46 hi Keyword      guifg=#cdd129 gui=none ctermfg=196
 47 hi PreProc      guifg=#ede39e gui=none ctermfg=187
 48 hi Number       guifg=#ede39e gui=none ctermfg=36
 49 hi Special      guifg=#acf0f2 gui=none ctermfg=159
```

Line numbers 42 and 43 have the necessary code. But, the functions names, identifiers and operators are still colored white. Is there any workaround to this problem, or have I done something wrong here? Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your colorscheme. The default C++ syntax file (`$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/cpp.vim` build on top of `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim`. Neither of those link any syntax groups to the `Identifier` and `Function` groups defined in your colorscheme.

You either need to find a more detailed syntax (I don't know of any), or write suitable `:syntax` extensions yourself (and put them into `~/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim`), or live with the amount of distinction that the default script provides.

Answer (score 0):

The `:highlight` commands are only part of what you need.  The harder part is the `:syntax` commands.  I do not see any in your file, so you are relying on the default definitions for `.cpp`.  To find the syntax group of something in your file, copy and paste the sample code from

```
:help synID()
```

I find that functions and variables in a `.cpp` file do not have any syntax group defined.